# how to pick a text input field value and store into the existing drop down list

Tags: javascript, dom

I am creating one drop down and in that dropdown I have a option called others, when others is selected, a new text box appear and user can enter any value. Now i want this entered value to be added to my drop down options.
Till now I could implement the first half and i am now unable to add the new value back to my drop down.

```
function CheckColors(val){
  var element=document.getElementById('popup');
  if (val=='others') {
    element.style.display='block';}
  else {
    element.style.display='none';
  }
}
```

```
  <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
    <option>pick a color</option>  
    <option>10%</option>
    <option>20%</option>
    <option>30%</option>
    <option>40%</option>
    <option value="others" >others
        
    </option>
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Add"/>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="popup" style='display:none;'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get the value that was added to the text box and create a new element to store in side the `select`.

Here, I am using [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create a new `option` when the user clicks `add`. Then, I'm setting it's content using `innerText` to what was added to the input.

I've done this when clicking the `add` button but it could be used elsewhere. I've also added a check so we don't add an empty value as an option.

```js
const CheckColors = (val) => {
  const element = document.getElementById('popup')
  if (val === 'others') {
    element.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

const addBtn = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]')
// Add a listener for when the add button is clicked
addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // get our dropdown and text box
  const dropdown = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
  const element = document.getElementById('popup')

  // Only add the value to the dropdown if it's not blank
  if (element.value.length !== 0) {
    // create the new option to add to our select
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    // Add the text that was in the text box
    option.innerText = element.value
    // Optionally give the option a value
    option.value = 'something'
    // Let's select this option too
    option.selected = true
    
    // Add the option to the select
    dropdown.appendChild(option)
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
  <option>pick a color</option>  
  <option>10%</option>
  <option>20%</option>
  <option>30%</option>
  <option>40%</option>
  <option value="others" >others

  </option>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Add"/>
</select>
<input type="text" id="popup" style='display:none;'/>
```

Comment: how to make the new value to be selected here? sorry I am new to js

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to mark the new option as selected with `option.selected`